# Update Table of a query in background

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to update the table of the query after click the button and send the form by ajax in background without reload the page.This action would be included in the success of the ajax post.

Any idea?
Thanks for the help

```js
$(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Actualizar Estado.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                window.location.replace("Administrar Pedidos.php");
              
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$consulta= "SELECT * FROM tfg.pedidos WHERE idpedido=(SELECT id FROM tfg.reservas WHERE fecha='$fechahoy' and hora<'$horamas' and hora>'$horamenos');";
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Error en la Realización de la Búsqueda");
echo "<table borde='2'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Idpedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Pedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Estado</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $columna['idpedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['pedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['estado']. "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
 } 
 echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla
}

?>
<form>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="idreserva" class="form-control" placeholder="  ¿Id de Reserva?" >
                           <div style="padding-left:80px"> 
                        <select  name="estado" class="form-control" >
                                <option value="nada" >¿Estado del Pedido?</option>
                                <option value="Completado">Completado</option>
                                <option value="Anulado">Anulado</option>
                                <option value="Realizando">Realizando</option>
                            </select>
                        <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span> Cambiar Estado</button>
                                <p></p>
                        </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? What is this code not doing that it should be doing??

Comment: Your query isn't called asynchronously, so you would have to refresh the page to update the table. One way to do this would be to create an API endpoint for the query instead and call it all using AJAX as a view - you could update the view when the form is submitted.

Comment: After click in the button and make the update sending the information to Actualizar Estado.php , i want to load the update table without reload the page.